# How to have VSCode look in other directories

Tags: visual-studio-code

An application I am working with has a large amount of shared source in a completely separate location.  How can I configure VSCode to look there when resolving a "Go to definition" request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a [multi-root workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces). Essentially just open both directories and save it as a workspace file.